# Norm of Functional in Real Hillbert Space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

I am working some problems that I am stuck on, i'm finding it hard to verify that my solution is correct or make any progress, since I can't find similar problems in books. I would appreciate some help:

Space = real Hilbert space $l_2(\mathbb{R})$
elements in the space: real sequences $x = \{x_{i}\}$

find the norm of : $<f,x>$ where 
$$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}x_{i}$$

My work:
1. I think the norm here is the Euclidian norm, if I'm correct, so I have norm of f = $\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_{i}x_{i})^2}$

but I'm not sure where to go from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually the operator norm, which can be expressed as:
$$\|f\| = \sup_{\|x\| \le 1} |f(x)|.$$
Note that, if $\|x\| \le 1$, i.e. $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_i|^2 \le 1$, then by Cauchy-Schwarz on $\Bbb{R}^n$,
$$|f(x)|^2 = \left|\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i\right|^2 \le \left(\sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|^2\right) \left(\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^2\right) \le \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2.$$
Thus, we have an upper bound; we have shown
$$\|f\| \le \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2}.$$
On the other hand, we can show that this is the supremum by showing it is a maximum. Consider the sequence
$$y = (a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n, 0, 0, \ldots),$$
and
$$x = \frac{y}{\|y\|} = \frac{y}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2}}.$$
Then $\|x\| \le 1$ and,
$$|f(x)| = \frac{|f(y)|}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2}} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2}} = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2},$$
achieving the upper bound. Thus the upper bound is a maximum and hence a supremum, i.e.
$$\|f\| = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2}.$$

Comment: (∑i=1n|ai|2)(∑i=1n|xi|2)≤∑i=1na2i. Thank you for your response, but why is this last inequality in Cauchy Schwarz step true?

Comment: @AnalysisShmalysis The last inequality comes from $\|x\|^2 \le 1$. The second last inequality is Cauchy-Schwarz. Note that it takes the form $|u \cdot v|^2 \le \|u\|^2 \|v\|^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.